# Can not Rebuild Project or Build Apk File

Tags: android

When i try to rebuild or build APK file, the error show :

**D:\MyApp\My_FCM\libs\preLollipopTransition\src\main\java\com\albinmathew\transitions\core\TransitionAnimation.java:
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.**

My preLollopopTransition gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

What's wrong ? Anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
lintOptions{
   checkReleaseBuilds false
 }
```

under release {}

Comment: Can you please share your TransitionAnimation.java class. There might be some error in this class due to deprecation.

Comment: My problem has been resolved, the libGoogleAnalyticsService in my app is too old and can not compatible with gradle. Then, i have updated latest version libGoogleAnalyticsService by add this line : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4' and update some method